# How to alter add content form to include a new setting panel?

Tags: hooks

Here is the code for creating a new Tab in the settings panel on "Add article" node.
But it is not displaying.. what could be the errors ?

```
function mltag_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
if ($form_id == 'article_node_form') {
drupal_set_message('Editing a node');
$form['mltag'] = array(
    '#type' => 'fieldset',
    '#title' => t('MLTag settings'),
    '#access' => TRUE,
    '#collapsible' => TRUE,
    '#group' => 'additional_settings',
    //'#attached' => array(
    //        'js' => array(drupal_get_path('module', 'autordf').'/autordf.js'),
    //),
    '#tree' => TRUE,
    '#weight' => -2,
    '#attributes' => array('class' => array('mltag-settings')),
);
$form['mltag']['enabled'] = array(
    '#type' => 'checkbox',
    '#title' => t('Generate tags use Mltag'),
    //'#default_value' => (empty($form['nid']['#value'])),
);
}   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code works perfectly for me; dropped straight into a form alter hook I get the following on the article add page:

[image: screenshot]

There are 3 reasons I can think of that might explain why you're not seeing the new tab:

1. You haven't cleared Drupal's caches since implementing the new hook (probably the most common cause for problems like this).
2. Your module isn't actually called "mltag", in which case your form alter hook will never actually be run.
3. Your code is in a file other than the main .module file. Hooks declared in files that are not explicitly included from the .module file will not necessarily be found when Drupal is updating the `module_implements` cache.

Comment: i've cleared the cache a number of times and the module name is also "mltag" there are other hooks working by the same module name.. but still not working for me..

Comment: Something else must be interfering with it then (as I say it works perfectly for me without any alteration); your best bet would be to try disabling modules methodically until you find the culprit

Comment: i did something like this too-
function mltag_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  
  drupal_set_message($form_id);
}
but did not get any message either !

Comment: Is the hook in a file called mltag.module?

Comment: yeah clive! evrything else is working fine.. dunno y this simple function is stuck and not working !